# Getting context on initialization from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, gcc

When compiling, I've run into this error quite a few times:

```
gcc -o index.o -c -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 "-D FUSE_USE_VERSION=31" index.c
index.c:40:12: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   .write = o_write,
            ^~~~~~~
```

The documentation for fuse tends to be inconsistent and sparse, so I'm left looking up other file system implementations on GitHub to find the proper method signature.

In this case, my problem was:

```
int o_write(const char*, char*, size_t, off_t, struct fuse_file_info*);
```

Should have been

```
int o_write(const char*, const char*, size_t, off_t, struct fuse_file_info*);
```

My question is:

When I see this warning, is there an easy way to know what the pointer type is *supposed* to be? I spent quite a bit of time tracking down [a proper implementation in sshfs](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs/blob/master/sshfs.c#L3036), but I feel like there is an easier way.

Comment: Well you could just look up the type of `write`

Comment: This [thread](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2002-10/msg00149.html) gives you some insight if you not go through yet, even though it doesn't talk about `const` keyword, but the explanation is applicable to pointers

Comment: gcc is pretty useless for these kind of warnings. gcc _knows_ which type that is expected and it _knows_ what type you passed. It just can't be bothered to let the programmer know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more or less an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) that reproduces the error message you show:

```
#include <sys/types.h>      // size_t, off_t

struct fuse_file_info;

struct whatever
{
    int (*write)(const char*, const char*, size_t, off_t, struct fuse_file_info*);
};

extern int o_wrong(const char*, char*, size_t, off_t, struct fuse_file_info*);
extern int o_write(const char*, const char*, size_t, off_t, struct fuse_file_info*);

struct whatever v1 = { .write = o_wrong };
struct whatever v2 = { .write = o_write };
```

When the file `fuse37.c` containing the code shown is compiled with GCC 7.2.0 (on a Mac running macOS High Sierra 10.13.2), I get:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c fuse37.c
fuse37.c:13:33: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
 struct whatever v1 = { .write = o_wrong };
                                 ^~~~~~~
fuse37.c:13:33: note: (near initialization for ‘v1.write’)
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$
```

The auxilliary information in the 'note' line tells you that you need to look for the definition of the `write` member (of the structure type `struct whatever`).

When you pass incorrect type arguments to a function call, you get better messages:

```
$ cat fuse47.c
    struct gizmotron;
    struct megatron;

    extern void calumniator(struct gizmotron *ptr);
    extern void transformer(struct megatron *arg);

    void calumniator(struct gizmotron *ptr)
    {
        transformer(ptr);
    }
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -c fuse47.c
fuse47.c: In function ‘calumniator’:
fuse47.c:9:17: error: passing argument 1 of ‘transformer’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
     transformer(ptr);
                 ^~~
fuse47.c:5:13: note: expected ‘struct megatron *’ but argument is of type ‘struct gizmotron *’
 extern void transformer(struct megatron *arg);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$
```

Now you can see that the note is explicit about the type expected and the type received.  I'm not sure whether the absence of the extra information in the initialization (as opposed to function call) is deliberate or an oversight.  Since the one diagnosis is possible, the other should be too.  It might be worth enquiring of the GCC maintenance team whether this could be upgraded.

Comment: This is a very annoying behavior of gcc indeed. I have too been writing dummy functions like that just for the sake of having gcc spit out some meaningful diagnostics. I've stopped doing that however - I just compiler the code with other C compiler and let it tell me which type that is wrong, since gcc couldn't.